# Selecting Date from a table where the column variable type is Varchar in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have database table *TABLE1* and there is Column *COLUMN1*. The variable declaration for that column is set up as `VARCHAR(20)`. Also, the column value can be `NULL` or `EMPTY`.

Suppose I have some 'dates' in that column (Format 12/01/2011) and I need a query to retrieve the dates, cannot be `NULL` or Empty and the dates are upto one year in the past (Suppose current date is 01/25/2012. I need the dates before 01/25/2011).

Please, help.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `varchar` rather than `date`?

Comment: `update table1 set column1 = null where column1 = ''; alter table table1 alter column column1 datetime null; select * from table1 where datediff(d, column1, getdate()) < 365;`

Comment: @GSerg Hmm... That my friend is tricky... :)

Comment: Not only is it `varchar`, it's _larger_ than a `date` type would be, too.  I mean, I can understand when you're trying to 'save space' and store it in an `int` field (YYYYMMDD format, of course - 4 bytes) - on DB2 a `date` type takes 10 bytes.  The `varchar` would only 'benefit' you if the majority of your fields were actually null/empty - but once field starts being filled, rows need to be re-allocated (right, so the record is contiguous?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the varchar to a date and then work on it.

```
SELECT convert(date, column1) as date
from table1
where convert(date, column1) < '01/25/2011'
and date is not null and date <> ''
```

Comment: While correct (and pretty much the only option if the table isn't `ALTER`ed), this will invalidate the use of indexes (will result in table scan).

Comment: I was assuming we're not doing any DDL modifications. But you're definitely right. If you can change the table schema, do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `date` instead of a varchar for your date since you are keeping it in that form? If you save your dates in a form of YYYY-MM-DD as a varchar you could even use:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 < DATE( "2011-01-01" )
```

but i would highly suggest you convert it to a date since they are using a similar format to the one you provided

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM  TABLE1 WHERE CONVERT(DATE, VC_DATE) < CONVERT(DATE,'01/25/2011')
AND LEN(VC_DATE)>0
```

Comment: I tested this using a small sample and it worked fine. Try it for yourself.

Comment: On DB2 at least, calling `LENGTH()` on a `null` field results in a `null` result (of course, it also doubles as a function equivalent to SQLServer's `DATALENGTH()`).  I don't know that I feel happy about a `null` field having `0` length (not always the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `COLUMN1` 
FROM   `TABLE1` 
WHERE  `COLUMN1` is NOT NULL AND
       `COLUMN1` != '' AND 
        STR_TO_DATE(`COLUMN1`, '%m/%d/%Y') < CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```